# Possible to delete rows based on the primary keys with realm and swift?

Tags: arrays, swift, primary-key, realm

So I basically have two arrays of primary ID's which I am comparing.
Simplified version:

```
let A: Set = [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
let B: Set = [2, 3, 5, 7] 
A.exclusiveOr(B).sort()
// [1, 2, 9]
```

I want to delete the primary keys that the result returns (so in this case, I want to delete the primary keys 1,2 and 9 from my database). I checked the documents from Realm.io, and at first glance there doesn't seem to be a way to delete these primary keys.

Is there a way that I can delete only the rows where the primary keys from my default.realm database are the ones that are returned from the `A.exclusiveOr(B).sort()` array??

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

You can delete objects with a given primary key by querying for the objects, then passing the returned `Results` to [`Realm.delete(_:)`](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/api/Classes/Realm.html#/s:FC10RealmSwift5Realm6deleteuRxs12SequenceTypeWx9Generator7Element_CS_6ObjectrFxT_). For example, if your primary key is named `id`:

```
try! realm.write {
    realm.delete(realm.filter("id IN %@", A.exclusiveOr(B)))
}
```